# ArrayFire OpenCL Issue

Tags: opencl, arrayfire

I have installed ArrayFire 3.8.0 using the binary installer as per the instructions mentioned in the documentation. All dependencies were installed before installing it. NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 11.3 is also installed. Installation was successful.

To test the installation, I have also build the examples as mentioned in the guide. There was no error during the build process. CPU & CUDA builds are running fine but OpenCL samples are not running. When I execute ./helloworld_opencl example, nothing happens on terminal. No process is shown in top & nvidia-smi.

Please guide me what could be the issue here. Clinfo command is running fine. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks